# Using Nant build project and run the NUnit

Tags: reference, nunit, nant, csproj

I want to use Nant build a project and import the dll file to execute NUnit.

But I don't konw how to write the xml code to build a  csproj file.

here is my xml :

---

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project name="Aaron.Guo.Second.Project" default="build" basedir=".">
  <property name="basename" value="A"/>
  <property name="debug" value="true"/>
  <target name="build">
    <csc target="library" debug="false" warnaserror="true" output="D:/A/bin/A1.dll">
      <sources basedir="D:/A">
        <include name="**/*.cs" />
      </sources>
      <references>
        <include name="D:/A/bin/*.dll"/>
      </references>
    </csc>
  </target>
</project>
```

---

I only know "include name" can build cs file

but it also show cannot  reference repeat using for the .us

i put reference file in the D:/A/bin/ directionary.

how can I write the xml?

Answer (score 1):

You should use `<exec>` http://nant.sourceforge.net/release/0.91/help/tasks/exec.html or `<msbuild>` http://nantcontrib.sourceforge.net/release/0.85-rc4/help/tasks/msbuild.html